# How to total "AS" column in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I need SUM of AS column "profit"and "purch_price". I tried few things group by stock.id etc but it is not giving me same answer. please let me know how to take their sum.

```
SELECT
    jobc_consumble.Stock_id,
    jobc_consumble.issued_qty,
    jobc_consumble.total,
    p_purch_stock.Price,
    p_purch_stock.Price * jobc_consumble.issued_qty AS "purch_price",
    jobc_consumble.total -(SELECT   purch_price) AS "profit"

FROM
    jobc_consumble
INNER JOIN p_purch_stock ON jobc_consumble.stock_id = p_purch_stock.stock_id
WHERE
        DATE_FORMAT(
        jobc_consumble.issue_time,
        '%Y-%m-%d'
    ) BETWEEN '2018-07-03' AND '2018-07-03'
```

Output should be like so :
[image]

I want sum of last two columns.

sum of PROFIT: 1105

sum of purch_price: 11000

Comment: As per the query Sum of PROFIT and purch_price is nothing but SUM(jobc_consumble.total)

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the logic in your `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
    j.Stock_id,
    j.issued_qty,
    j.total,
    p.Price,
    p.Price * j.issued_qty AS purch_price,
    j.total - (p.Price * j.issued_qty) AS profit
FROM jobc_consumble j
INNER JOIN p_purch_stock p
    ON j.stock_id = p.stock_id
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(j.issue_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2018-07-03';
```

For some notes, the only alternative to repeating the purchase price logic would be to wrap your current query as a subquery and reuse the alias.  But, that would probably not be too performant.  Your `DATE_FORMAT` expression does not make much sense, because the range is just a single day.  If you don't like my version, then let us know what logic you really intended.